# What causes an OLE DoDragDrop dragged item to change to the no-drop icon over a drop target?

Tags: com, drag-and-drop, ole

By the no-drop icon I mean the circle with a slash indicating that you can't drop in the given location. Which function is responsible for triggering this icon change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [excerpt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716266(VS.60).aspx) gives the answer:

> Modifying the mouse pointer to
>   indicate how a control will respond if
>   the data is dropped onto it involves
>   two steps: determining what type of
>   data is in the DataObject object using
>   the GetFormat method, and then setting
>   the effect argument of the OLEDragOver
>   event to inform the source what drop
>   effects are allowed for this control.
>
> **The OLEDragOver Event**
>
> When a target control’s OLEDropMode
>   property is set to Manual, the
>   OLEDragOver event is triggered
>   whenever dragged data passes over the
>   control.
>
> The effect argument of the OLEDragOver
>   event is used to specify what action
>   would be taken if the object were
>   dropped. When this value is set, the
>   source’s OLEGiveFeedback event is
>   triggered. The OLEGiveFeedback event
>   contains its own effect argument,
>   which is used to provide visual
>   feedback to the user on what action
>   will be taken when the selection is
>   dragged — i.e., the mouse pointer is
>   changed to indicate a copy, move, or
>   "no drop" action.

[alt text http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/3531/dragseqdrag.gif](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/3531/dragseqdrag.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the DragEnter function in the [IDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679679%28VS.85%29.aspx) COM interface and the GiveFeedback function in the [IDropSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690071%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface